# Difference Between Webhooks and CI/CDs

Tags: git, continuous-integration, webhooks, continuous-deployment, github-actions

I know that Webhooks are used to trigger server-side actions from a hosted git repository, and that CI/CD stands for Continuous Integration & Continuous Deployment/Delivery for a hosted git repository, but what is the key difference, specifically when they are both offered by a single git hosting service provider like GitLab or GitHub? (For GitLab these refer to Webhooks and CI/CD, while for GitHub these refer to Webhooks and GitHub Actions.)

Documentations vaguely details how Webhooks can be and is used to trigger CI/CDs, but meanwhile, vendor-provided CI/CDs can function even when no explicit webhook is added to a git repository. Does this mean that there is a Webhook under the hood for every hosted git repository that uses vendor-provided CI/CD?

My understanding from the above is that explicit Webhooks (contrary to underlying ones) can be used to trigger 3rd party CI/CDs, while git hosting service providers' CI/CDs are hosted and run from the same party. Is this correct?

Thank you very much for whoever posts an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Webhooks and CI/CD are two different technologies that you often find used together.

Webhooks are set up to post data in real time to consuming applications. Webhooks generally post to a URL endpoint that is set up to accept information from it. In the case of CI this could be a webhook that posts information about a commit when it happens. See here for more info - https://codeburst.io/what-are-webhooks-b04ec2bf9ca2

CI/CD exist to automate the deployments and building of software. A common usage for one is to build software for the different environments it may require, e.g. dev, staging, production. A popular CI tool is Team City - https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/

To reiterate, webhooks aren't trying to solve the same problem as CI/CD but they do extend the functionality of what it can do.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Is there a webhook under the hood for CI/CDs provided by GitHub or GitLab, etc? (i.e., whenever a git event is posted to a remote, if a vendor-provided CI/CD is configured for that remote, a webhook (not visible on the user interface) is triggered, which then triggers the corresponding CI/CD?) Like this: `git event => [webhook] => CI/CD`)

Comment: It's very possible that is what's going on under the hood, however I'm not too familiar with the CI software provided by GitHub or GitLab so I will have to do some research into that. These providers do give you the option to add your own webhook. Think of it like a 'reverse API', you set up a webhook on their end and they post relevant data to you whenever a trigger (git push for example) is called. An example of this is posting to your Slack channels when a build is complete or fails, rather than you querying the service, the data is pushed to you in real time.